# Can a class inside a class call a getter method from the outer class?

Tags: c++

I have a class inside a class.

The outer class does some processing to generate an array of values.

I want the inner class to be able to access the outer class' array.

Is there a clean way to achieve this?

I'm thinking to have a method in the outer class that calls a method in the inner class sending him the address of the array and the inner class needs to hold a pointer in its private member section in order to later point to it by assignment from the method that receives the address. But this feels a little clunky.

Comment: does this help?
https://www.reddit.com/r/cpp_questions/comments/btf6m1/class_a_contains_class_b_member_can_class_b/eoy076p?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x

Comment: An example may help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upon construction you can pass a reference of outer class to the constructor of the inner class. Using the reference you can call any function of the outer class.

```
// The actual definition of the inner class.
class inner {
  public:
    inner(outer& o) : outer_(o) // Set the reference.
    {

    }

    // The function using the data in outer.
    void do_stuff() 
    {
      int x = outer_.get_data() + 5;
    }

  private:
    // A reference to the outer class.
    outer& outer_;

}

// The actual outer class.
class outer {
 public:
   outer() : inner_(*this) // Set the reference using the this object.
   {

   }

   // This is the function you would like to call.
   int get_data();

 private:
   inner inner_;
}
```

Comment: Hi Bart, Where is the outer reference passing anything into the constructor of the inner class? Doesn't inner need to be declared like this `Inner inner{this}` or something? Also, if I merely want access to the array, don't need a getter function for it, is there an even simpler way?

Comment: It's nice, but `inner` is not inside `outer`. You can achieve it easily though: 1) move the forward declaration inside `outer`. 2) define inner as `class outer::inner`.

Comment: @aName check the constructor, `this` is passed to the inner class there (you could also do it directly when declared, like you said)

Comment: You need to forward declare `outer`, then define `inner`, then define `outer`. In this order you get an incomplete type error.

Comment: @aName You can access the array in the `outer` instance directly through the `_outer` from inside `inner` without needing to make a getter.

Comment: You should [avoid prefixing identifiers with an underscore `_`](http://eel.is/c++draft/lex.name#3), use underscore as a suffix instead (*i.e.* `inner_`). It's legal in this case but better to simply not do it.

Comment: Yes I removed the forward declaration and move the definition of the class. You can only do forward declarations with references and pointers.

@Paul good point about the _.

Answer (score 0):

C++ has a concept of the nested class. A nested class, which is declared in another enclosing class. It is a member and has the same access rights as any other member of the enclosing class. But the members of an enclosing class have no special access to members of a nested class.you can refer to this sample code. Hope this will help

```
class Outer {       
   private:    
       int arry[]; 

   class inner { 
         private:
         int innerArr[];
      void Fun(Outer *e) { 
        innerArr = e->arry;   

      }        
   }; 
}; 
int main(){
Outer out;
Outer::inner in;
in.Fun(out);
```

}

Comment: This looks much cleaner/simpler, (and is basically what I have now) but how to I pass Outer's address to fun. I did it by having a function in outer that will call Fun

Comment: As mention, enclosing class (outer) can not access member of nested class, so you can not access Fun in the function of outer, I guess. Updated the code. I, myself never tried with nested class. But hope this will work for you

Answer (score 0):

Okay, here it is in full. Key points:

- C++ has nested classes, however that's a 100% compile-time thing dealing with scoping and encapsulation, the class instances are 100% independent.
- Therefore if you want either class to use the other in any way, it must either create an instance or accept one.
- (and then, given an outer instance, the inner class is allowed to access its private parts that's the only thing that actually differs from normal scoping).

So knowing that, here is a concrete example.
 → Outer owns a vector of Inners.
 → Inner needs to use its owning Outer instance
 ➥ say Outer could be some kind of List and Inner some kind of Item

```
class Outer
{
public:  // can be private, in which case Inner won't be usable from outside
    class Inner
    {
        Outer & m_outer;
    public:
        Inner(Outer & outer) : m_outer(outer) {}
        void doOuterMagic() { m_outer.doMagic(); }
    };

public:
    void addInner() { m_inners.emplace_back(*this); }

private: // could be public, but I want to illustrate Inner access to private members
    void doMagic() { std::cout <<"magic"; }

private:
    std::vector<Inner> m_inners;
};
```

As with any class, you may also define it below the outer class if it's more readable. You'd do it like this:

```
class Outer
{
public:  // can be private, in which case Inner won't be usable from outside
    class Inner;
public:

    // ... unchanged ...

};

class Outer::Inner  // note the scoping here
{
    // ... exactly what was in class Inner above
};
```

**Notes:**

- Any relationship Outer and Inner have it up to your design, C++ assumes none.
- If Outer works in close relationship with Inner, it's pretty common to have Outer create Inner instances and pass itself to them, as I did in `addInner` here.
- I made `m_outer` a reference, but this prevents `Inner` from satisfying *Assignable requirements. If you need the class to satisfy those, make it a pointer instead.

Comment: Thank you for your time. It's amazing how such little code and can make the mind boggle so much!